# IQueryable expression type mismatch

Tags: c#, reflection, expression, system.reflection

I want to create an extension method for a LINQ expression but I'm stuck. What I need is just to create a method which will add a specific *Where* clause to a `Queryable`. Something like:

```
var hierarchy = "a string";
Session.Query<SomeClass>.Where(x => x.Layer.Hierarchy.StartsWith(hierarchy) ||
                                    x.Layer.Hierarchy == hierarchy);
```

to become:

```
var hierarchy = "a string";
Session.Query<SomeClass>.LayerHierarchy(x => x.Layer, hierarchy);
```

And do that Where logic inside. So basicly the extension method `LayerHierarchy()` is running over the `Queryable` of `T` but the subject is of type `Layer`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> LayerHierarchy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
                                                  Expression<Func<T, Layer>> layer,
                                                  string hierarchy)

{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Layer), "layer");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Hierarchy");

    // StartWith method
    MethodInfo methodStartsWith = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var valueStartsWith = Expression.Constant(string.Concat(hierarchy, "|"), typeof(string));

    var methodExpStartsWith = Expression.Call(propertyExp, methodStartsWith, valueStartsWith);
    var startsWith = Expression.Lambda<Func<Layer, bool>>(methodExpStartsWith, parameterExp);

    // Equals method
    MethodInfo methodEquals = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var valueEquals = Expression.Constant(hierarchy, typeof(string));

    var methodExpEquals = Expression.Call(propertyExp, methodEquals, valueEquals);
    var equals = Expression.Lambda<Func<Layer, bool>>(methodExpEquals, parameterExp);

    return query
                .Where(startsWith)
                .Where(equals);
}
```

Everything works fine above the `return` line. It complains that...

> Cannot convert from `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Layer, bool>>` to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, int, bool>>`

when trying to pass the expressions to `query.Where()` method. How can I fix it?

Comment: Would that error be in the first or second `Where`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto first, but if I take it out, it gives me the same error on the second `Where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is how you are creating the `Lambda`s. They should begin from `T`, not from `Layer`:

```
var startsWith = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodExpStartsWith, parameterExp);
var equals = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodExpEquals, parameterExp);
```

However, in order for this to work, you are missing one more `PropertyExpression`.

Your query now looks like:

> (Layer)x => x.Hierarchy.StartsWith(...)

When, what you want is this:

> (T)x => x.Layer.Hierarchy.StartsWith(...)

So, use this instead:

```
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
var layerExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Layer");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(layerExp, "Hierarchy");
```

Your logic should change a little though, since two `.Where` will generate an `AND` condition between them, and it seems like you want one of them to be true (`StartsWith` or `Equals`), so:

```
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
var layerExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Layer");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(layerExp, "Hierarchy");

// StartWith method
MethodInfo methodStartsWith = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
var valueStartsWith = Expression.Constant(string.Concat(hierarchy, "|"), typeof(string));

var methodExpStartsWith = Expression.Call(propertyExp, methodStartsWith, valueStartsWith);

// Equals method
MethodInfo methodEquals = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
var valueEquals = Expression.Constant(hierarchy, typeof(string));

var methodExpEquals = Expression.Call(propertyExp, methodEquals, valueEquals);

var orElseExp = Expression.OrElse(methodExpStartsWith, methodExpEquals);
var orElse = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orElseExp, parameterExp);

return query.Where(orElse);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already tried that and I was running the project to get the right error message to post it to you. It gives me: `ParameterExpression of type 'Layer' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type Cell'`, when I run like `Session.Query<Cell>().LayerHierarchy(x => x.Layer, hierarchy)`.

Comment: It happens in that very line of `var startsWith...`.

Comment: I realized that two `Where()` makes an `and` condition, but what I need is an `or` condition, do you know how can I set it to work as `or` ? It is not the main subject of the question so if it becomes to complex, I can try by myself.

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to make it work like `LayerHierarchy(x => x.Prop1.Prop2)`? Using like that broke it. I have made a recursive method that navigate to the last property to use with `Expression.Property` and set into `Expression.Call` calls, but then, the base type changes and I get that convert error again. I can share that recursive method if you like. I hope it is possible.. haha

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown That should be another question, IMO. I might be able to look into that tomorrow and see what's the problem